# How to slide in a UIView in a portrait mode application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, landscape-portrait

I am working on an iPhone application that runs in portrait mode only. This app have only view controller and 1 interface file (.xib). I want to slide in some additional views when user taps on button on either toolbar / navigation bar. Let's say like info button on navigation bar. When I click it UIView should slide in from bottom. And when user taps on done button on that view that view slides down. I have made separate uiview for those views in same xib. I also looked into couple of transition examples by others but could not got that concept. Can any one give me some pointers on this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reset the frames through animation like

```
UIView *view= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,-100.0f,320.0f,100.0f)];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:[self view]      cache:YES];  

[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f,100.0f)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I am quite new to this. Can you tell me what exactly you are doing ? I want to give slide in effect and with what you are given I guess I will be getting culr effect and it will show same view after that. I want it to show some other view.

Comment: In the code above, the view is initially off screen because the Y coordinate is -100.  Then an animation block is started, the view frame is changed to its final position (Y=0).  Finally commitAnimations starts the animation where the view will animate from it's original position to the final position.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm :) @ Progrmr : Thanks for explanation :)

Comment: @Sumit Lonkar nice to know that it worked for you.. i was away to give any details.. you can vote up for the comment given by @ progrmr :)

Comment: i did that earlier n did it again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean modal view transitions.  Like what the app store does when you enter a gift card on the iPhone.

Example:

```
UIViewController *controllerForSecondView = ..;
controllerForSecondView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:controllerForSecondView animated:YES];
```

Then make a done button in the second xib and call:

```
dismissModalViewController
```

Comment: Its not a view controller, its just UIview. I could have used your suggestion but I have couple controls on that view associated with rootviewcontroller.